# Calculate distance between two rotated elements

Tags: javascript, geometry

Hi I want to calculate the perpendicular distance between two rotated elements, when rotation is 0 I use `el1.getBoundingClientRect().x - el2.getBoundingClientRect().x` and it gives me right distance, but for rotated elements, it does not work as it gives the perpendicular distance between the vertexes (the distance of bounding rectangles, how can I get x? thanks!
[image: Ex. one what I am looking for]

[image: The result when elements are roteted]

https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-thunder-mxqbc?file=/src/index.js

Comment: If you know the angle of rotation you can un-rotate the elements, then calculate the distance and finally rotate the elements back.

Comment: Yes, I am in the same way, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If differences of vertex coordinates of two rectangles  before rotation were `(dx, dy)`, then after rotattion by angle `fi` new differences are:

```
 nx = dx * cos(fi) - dy * sin(fi)
 ny = dx * sin(fi) + dy * cos(fi)
```

If we multiply the first equation by `cos(fi)` and the second one by `sin(fi)`, then add them, we can find needed value

```
dx = nx * cos(fi) + ny * sin(fi)
```

(assuming you know vertex difference in rotated state)

For example below: `dx was 25, cos(fi)=4/5, sin(fi)=3/5`
After rotation: `nx = 5, ny = 35, we can find dx = 5*4/5 + 25*3/5 = 4+21 = 25`

[image]
[image]

Comment: It gives the same distance as `el1.getBoundingClientRect().x - el2.getBoundingClientRect().x` `113`,when deg is `30`, `100` when deg is `0`, If I use `-30` for the formula it gives `50` instead of `100`.

Comment: Bear in mind that the angle fi is in radians for this.

Comment: I added example

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-thunder-mxqbc?file=/src/index.js you can check it here, CSS rotate rotates to element's center. @mrblewog yes I use radians.

Comment: y1-y for **corresponding vertices** must be about -4 rather than 95, that is why your calculation gives wrong result

Comment: I calculate subtraction small rectangle y  by a large rectangle, I can do the same form bottom side but it won be -4.

Comment: x1-x = 113 for bottom left vertices. For these vertices we can see small y-difference. x-difference for top left vertices is xmsller than 100